# How to upgrade ruby version of ruby on rails app using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

How do I safely upgrade my ruby on rails app to use a new ruby version, using rvm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your app is my_app and you are using ruby version a.b.c and want to go to ruby version x.y.z.

**Step 0**

Before starting, make sure you have the up to date version of rvm

```
rvm get stable
rvm reload
```

**Step 1**

First if you do not have a gemset for your current ruby version create one and make it the default. This gives you an easy way to go back if your upgrade breaks your tests. If you do not want to do this, go to step 2.

```
rvm gemset create my_app_abc
```

The switch to that gemset and install the gems into that gemset, and make it the default gemset for the directory

```
rvm a.b.c@my_app_abc
bundle
rvm --ruby-version use a.b.c@my_app_abc
```

**Step 2**

Now upgrade to the new ruby version and create a gemset for it.

```
rvm install x.y.z
rvm use x.y.z
rvm gemset create my_app_xyz
rvm x.y.z@my_app_xyz
```

It is considered best practice to specify the ruby version in your Gemfile so
make sure you have `ruby 'x.y.z'` at the top of your Gemfile. Then

```
gem install bundle
bundle
```

This is where the fun can start, you may get errors at this point and use a combination of following the error instructions or googling for help, etc to solve them.  When you can bundle successfully, then run all your tests.

When your tests have all passed, then you have successfuly upgraded. If you get stuck, you can go back to your old installation, using `rvm a.b.c@my_app_abc`.

Once  you are happy with your new installation then do

```
rvm --ruby-version use x.y.z@my_app_xyz
```

to make this the default setup for this app. This means when you change into this app from other projects, it will automatically load ruby version x.y.z and the corresponding gemset.

According to this [blog](https://blog.engineyard.com/do-we-still-need-rvm-gemsets), if you always precede commands by `bundle exec` you do not need to use gemsets. In that case, you would simply do

```
rvm --ruby-version use x.y.z
```